# How to test Warden strategies using RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, single-sign-on, warden

I am using Warden and have written a couple of custom strategies for signing users in. Some use params that the user has typed in a page, some use a cookie, some try an external API, etc.

The question now is: as much as I've looked, I haven't found any example of how to test these strategies in detail.

How can I ensure that more than one strategy is not outputting valid for a given situation? Or that the order in which they are examined is correct? And also that their behaviour once trying to login is correct?

Is it possible to test them without having the "full stack" of a request? Is that desirable?

Even if I end up trying to do so, how can I achieve this? I've had a look at some resources, such as [warden-rspec-rails](https://github.com/ajsharp/warden-rspec-rails) for instance but I would appreciate any light and pointers on the proper way to tackle this.